# Cygwin's cmake does not match for CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME

Tags: c++, regex, cmake, cygwin, match

I'm having a stange behavior on cygwin using cmake.
I try to check the OS in my CMakeLists.txt but is seems that this particular case does not work...
Here is an example that raises my problem:

```
set (FOO "BAR")

message(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME})

if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "CYGWIN")
    message("EQUALS CYGWIN")
endif()

if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "CYGWIN")
    message("MATCHES CYGWIN")
endif()

if (${FOO} MATCHES "BAR")
    message("MATCHES BAR")
endif()
```

CMake prints:

```
CYGWIN
EQUALS CYGWIN
MATCHES BAR
```

And not the expected "MATCHES CYGWIN".
I find this weird that it works for other variables (like FOO here).
Is there something I am doing wrong?

Configuration:

- cmake version 2.8.11.2
- uname CYGWIN_NT-6.1

PS: I also checked with FOO = "CYGWIN", and it does not match neither. It seems that just this particular string does not work with MATCHES...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Cause

Signature of the `if` cmake command is

```
if(<variable|string> MATCHES regex)
```

but not

```
if(<string> MATCHES regex)
```

This means that *variable* `CYGWIN` checked **first**, and if there is no such variable, then `CYGWIN` **string** used.

#### Prove

Just try to print `CYGWIN` variable (see [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable:CYGWIN)):

```
> cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(foo)
message("cygwin variable: ${CYGWIN}")
> cmake -H. -B_builds
...
cygwin variable: 1
...
```

#### Detailed

```
if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "CYGWIN")
    # variable CYGWIN vs variable CYGWIN, i.e. 1 == 1
    message("EQUALS CYGWIN") # success
endif()

if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "CYGWIN")
    # variable CYGWIN (i.e. 1) vs regex CYGWIN
    message("MATCHES CYGWIN") # fail
endif()

if (${FOO} MATCHES "BAR")
    # string BAR vs string BAR
    message("MATCHES BAR") # success
endif()
```

#### Antidote

Avoid using commands with `<variable|string>` signature as much as possible, because
**any** name can be applied to variable:

```
> cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(foo)
set("/this/is/definitely/not/a/variable/name" "surprise!")
message("${/this/is/definitely/not/a/variable/name}")
> cmake -H. -B_builds
...
surprise!
...
```

For example you can use [string](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:string) command:

```
string(COMPARE EQUAL "${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}" "CYGWIN" is_cygwin)
if(is_cygwin)
  message("Hello, cygwin!")
endif()
```

Note that in your particular case you can simply use `CYGWIN` variable check:

```
if(CYGWIN)
  message("Hello, cygwin!")
endif()
```

#### Related

- [CMake compare to empty string with STREQUAL failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982340/cmake-compare-to-empty-string-with-strequal-failed)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The idea was to have a uniform way of checking the platform where cmake is running. Do you have a general solution (let say to check linux, cygwin, osx and win32)?

Answer (score 2):

Changing this:

```
if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "CYGWIN")
```

to:

```
if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "CYGWIN")
```

has the desired effect.