# Can I use CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR, defined in a toolchain file, in CMakeLists?

Tags: c++, cmake, arm, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I'd like to add Raspberry Pi as a cross compilation target to a C++ project which uses CMake. Following the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162072/installing-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler) question, I've set up the environment successfully.

The project has many build targets already, all of them defined in the main CMakeLists.txt in a quite ugly way (it's an old project). In this file, there are some compiler flags set, depending on the CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR variable, for example:

```
if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR} MATCHES "^arm")
    # do something
endif ()
```

According to the [guide](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling), I should set this in my Raspberry toolchain file. I've added `SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)`, but I can't access this from the CMakeLists, because this becomes an empty string there. I don't have this problem with the other variables, like CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME. Using `message()`, I can see that it is still available in the toolchain file, but becomes empty after that.

Is there any way to use CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR in CMakeLists.txt? Or, is it available only in the toolchain file intentionally?

I'm using CMake 2.8.12.2.

Comment: Did you actually load the toolchain file? I suggest you generate your project from a clean build directory using cmake-gui: it will prompt you asking if you want to use a toolchain the first time you configure.

Comment: A clean build fixed this issue, thanks! The toolchain file was loaded correctly, but looks like CMake cached the variable before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this was a caching issue after all - building in a clean directory fixed the problem. Though I still wonder how did it become an empty string...

Comment: May be when you didn't specify the toolchain file when you did cmake top_dir/CMakeLists.txt for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have fallen victim to CMake's [double expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982340/cmake-compare-to-empty-string-with-strequal-failed). Try using this instead:

```
if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR MATCHES "^arm")
    # do something
endif ()
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, the variable is still empty.