# CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR value in toolchain file not visible in top level CMakeLists.txt file

Tags: cmake

I have cmake project which I've successfully set up and used for cross compiling with a toolchain file.

I have a separate variable I want to set in my top level cmake file based on the value of the CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR variable that is set in the tool chain file. But when referenced in the top level cmake file, the value of CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR does not have the value from the toolchain file.

I can reproduce the conditions with a simple cmake file and one line toolchain file.

If I have the following cmake file:

```
project(ToolchainTest C)
message("CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")
```

and run

```
cmake .
```

I get

```
CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x86_64
```

as I expect.

With the following one line toolchain file "toolchain.cmake":

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)
```

when I run

```
cmake . -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=toolchain.cmake
```

I get exactly the same output, x86_64, and *not* aarch64 as I expected.

I looked over the following related posts, but as I'm just printing the value and not doing a string match (in the example) I don't think they apply.

[Can I use CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR, defined in a toolchain file, in CMakeLists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986677/can-i-use-cmake-system-processor-defined-in-a-toolchain-file-in-cmakelists)

[CMake compare to empty string with STREQUAL failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982340/cmake-compare-to-empty-string-with-strequal-failed)

I'm using cmake version 3.13.4 on Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Have you seen the question and response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41272239/3987854)? The toolchain file is not read until CMake encounters the `project()` command.

Comment: There's a lot of very good information there. I've added a project directive to my sample cmake file base on my initial reading, but it didn't change the outcome. I'll continue to look into the other references cited in that question.

Comment: My previous comment may not be entirely correct, it appears that even without the `project()` command, CMake still gathers the system/compiler information before processing the CMakeLists file (it pretends there is a `project()` command). This is when I imagine the toolchain is first parsed. Your issue may be more subtle, perhaps, a cached vs non-cached variable issue...

Comment: I've tried set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64 CACHE STRING "doc") and set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64 CACHE STRING "doc" FORCE) with no effect. I'm also trying to make sure I clean out my generated files every time.

Maybe worth noting too that -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR= on the command line also seems to have no effect.

Comment: Is your toolchain ever has an effect? E.g. if you firstly run `cmake .` without toolchain then further `cmake .` would ignore toolchain setting. Until you clear the cache.

Comment: I'm trying to me careful about clearing the cache from the build directory (rm -rf *) before I run the generator.

I see an effect in the sense that I've added message command in the toolchain and in the CMakeLists.txt file and I can see them print messages as I expect when I expect.

I've also set a user variable ("FOO" in this case) in the toolchain file and I see the effect both in the toolchain and in the CMakeList's file when I print the values using message()

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing if anyone can reproduce the issue with the stripped down file content I posted in the question.

Comment: @M.Krajnak -  I am facing a similar issue. How did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. The answer is that when `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` is not set, CMake overwrites `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` ([source code](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/fbea5d9f9945363f35aa16c3edcf0924e3dc4686/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake#L178)). This is arguably a bug but regardless is how CMake behaves.

The solution is to set both, even if you're compiling for the same system:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a better way than include it. But it should be included by the cmake internally.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(ToolchainTest C)

if(DEFINED CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)
    include(${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE})
endif()
```

This happens because cmake overwrites mentioned variable. Let's debug with --trace parameter

```
C:/test/build/CMakeFiles/3.19.0-rc2/CMakeSystem.cmake(6):  include(C:/test/toolchain.cmake )
   Called from: [2] C:/test/build/CMakeFiles/3.19.0-rc2/CMakeSystem.cmake
                [1] C:/test/CMakeLists.txt
C:/test/toolchain.cmake(1):  set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64 )
   Called from: [3] C:/test/toolchain.cmake
                [2] C:/test/build/CMakeFiles/3.19.0-rc2/CMakeSystem.cmake
                [1] C:/test/CMakeLists.txt
C:/test/build/CMakeFiles/3.19.0-rc2/CMakeSystem.cmake(8):  set(CMAKE_SYSTEM Windows-10.0.19044 )
   Called from: [2] C:/test/build/CMakeFiles/3.19.0-rc2/CMakeSystem.cmake
                [1] C:/test/CMakeLists.txt
C:/test/build/CMakeFiles/3.19.0-rc2/CMakeSystem.cmake(9):  set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows )
   Called from: [2] C:/test/build/CMakeFiles/3.19.0-rc2/CMakeSystem.cmake
                [1] C:/test/CMakeLists.txt
C:/test/build/CMakeFiles/3.19.0-rc2/CMakeSystem.cmake(10):  set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 10.0.19044 )
   Called from: [2] C:/test/build/CMakeFiles/3.19.0-rc2/CMakeSystem.cmake
                [1] C:/test/CMakeLists.txt
C:/test/build/CMakeFiles/3.19.0-rc2/CMakeSystem.cmake(11):  set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR AMD64 )
   Called from: [2] C:/test/build/CMakeFiles/3.19.0-rc2/CMakeSystem.cmake
                [1] C:/test/CMakeLists.txt
```

So, As you can see CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR is set to aarch64 (by toolchain) and then overwritten to AMD64 if somebody knows why would be nice to get it. CMakeSystem.cmake just has a construction like

- set(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM* ...
- include(toolchain.cmake")
- set(CMAKE_SYSTEM* ... including CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR

How to stop this? Until we have found the answer to this question you can use mentioned workaround at the top of my post.

[CMake: In which order are files parsed (cache, toolchain, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503631/cmake-in-which-order-are-files-parsed-cache-toolchain-etc)