# CMAKE string comparison fails

Tags: cmake

I want to optionally add some library paths in my CMakeLists file and the way to do it to is to have a variable set as:

```
set(MYLIBDIR "DEFAULT")
```

If the user wants to specify a custom directory he will change it to:

```
set(MYLIBDIR /path/to/dir1
/path/to/dir2)
```

So in order to check if the user has indeed provided extra directories I check:

```
if(NOT ${MYLIBDIR} STREQUAL "DEFAULT")
 link_directories(${MYLIBDIR})
endif()
```

When I try to do this I am getting an error from cmake.
Is there a way to concatenate all of the elements of a variable before the string comparison?

Comment: Could you please also give the error message you got? Can you try `if(NOT MYLIBDIR STREQUAL "DEFAULT")`? For more details see [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables) and [CMake compare to empty string with STREQUAL failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982340/cmake-compare-to-empty-string-with-strequal-failed).

Comment: The error is: `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:264 (if):
  if given arguments:
    "NOT" " /path/to/dir1" " /path/to/dir2" "STREQUAL" "DEFAULT"
  Unknown arguments specified
`

Comment: Oh thank you very much. I found the answer in the first link that you referenced. 
I had to write `if(NOT "${MYLIBDIR}" STREQUAL "DEFAULT")`

Comment: You're welcome. Then this was a quoting issue. I've put some details in my answer found below. And I added a link to [cmake: when to quote variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847655/cmake-when-to-quote-variables) which in this case probably explains the inner working better then the previous two links.

Answer (score 38):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

Concatenating a list would simply be achieved by putting quotes around the variable reference:

```
if(NOT "${MYLIBDIR}" STREQUAL "DEFAULT")
```

would be the same as

```
if(NOT "/path/to/dir1;/path/to/dir2" STREQUAL "DEFAULT")
```

But I would recommend

```
if(NOT MYLIBDIR STREQUAL "DEFAULT")
```

For more details see

- [cmake: when to quote variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847655/cmake-when-to-quote-variables)